# Anyway to auto set jmeter assertions to initial responses?

Tags: jmeter

I am building out a test suite in jmeter and want to set the assertions to the initial responses that I get from the api calls. Is there any way to do this besides copy pasta?

For clarity each individual call has its own assertion, which for the moment is the response it is receiving.

I want the assertions to be populated by the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood currectly - you are coming up with some JMeter-Baseline script - you also assume that the response you get now is correct - that is what you expect to get it in future as well , so you want to put the response data in the assertion.

If yes, JMeter will not remember the initial responses. So you need to create your script accordingly.

You can have a beanshell postprocessor to write the the responsedata in a CSV file. Later you modify the script to look for the assertion string from CSV file to compare. This is the statement to get the Response Data.

```
prev.getResponseDataAsString()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [How to Use JMeter Assertions in 3 Easy Steps](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide, JMeter Assertions have their scope.

If you put an assertion at the same level as all requests it'll apply to all of them. See image below for explanation:

[image: Assertions Scope]

Comment: What I mean is that each individual call has it's own assertion, which for the moment is the response it receives for that call. I am not trying to assign a single assertion to multiple calls. At the moment I am having to go to each individual response and copy/paste it into the assertion. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CSV file with the URL and the assertion string you want to match.